# How do I set the navbar fixed and the menu on the right without spoiling everything?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make the menu as in this web page: https://socialyte.codeplus.it/wall.html

The problem is that if my navbar is put `position: fixed` everything is damaged, how can I solve it?

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid row p-0 m-0">
            <div class="col-2 bg-black sidebar">

            </div>
            <div class="col-10 p-0 m-0 body">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-dark inline">
                    <ul class="d-flex navbar-custom navbar-nav mr-auto d-inline">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inicio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Perfil</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Publicar</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Cerrar Sesión</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="col-md-10 offset-1">
                    <div class="card mt-3 border-0 rounded-0">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                        <p class="card-text">
                          Some quick example text to build on the card title
                          and make up the bulk of the card's content.
                        </p>
                        <a href="#!" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                        <a href="#!" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card mt-3 border-0 rounded-0">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                        <p class="card-text">
                          Some quick example text to build on the card title
                          and make up the bulk of the card's content.
                        </p>
                        <a href="#!" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                        <a href="#!" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card mt-3 border-0 rounded-0">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                        <p class="card-text">
                          Some quick example text to build on the card title
                          and make up the bulk of the card's content.
                        </p>
                        <a href="#!" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                        <a href="#!" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card mt-3 border-0 rounded-0">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                        <p class="card-text">
                          Some quick example text to build on the card title
                          and make up the bulk of the card's content.
                        </p>
                        <a href="#!" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                        <a href="#!" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card mt-3 border-0 rounded-0">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                        <p class="card-text">
                          Some quick example text to build on the card title
                          and make up the bulk of the card's content.
                        </p>
                        <a href="#!" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                        <a href="#!" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card mt-3 border-0 rounded-0">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                        <p class="card-text">
                          Some quick example text to build on the card title
                          and make up the bulk of the card's content.
                        </p>
                        <a href="#!" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                        <a href="#!" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
.body {
  background-color: #EDF1F5;
  margin-left: 16.69%!important;
}

.sidebar {
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}

.navbar .navbar-custom{
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
}

nav {
    background-color: #4F5467;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may get you on the right track. You will still need to adjust the width of the body and sidebar classes. Notice I added a simple hello just to see something in the sidebar. * EDIT Also, take your nav element out of the element with the body class.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xjENLm

That may be easier for you to play with. It is using bootstrap.

```css
.body {
  background-color: #EDF1F5;
  margin-left: 16.69%!important;
  margin-top: 65px;
}

.sidebar {
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
}

.navbar .navbar-custom{
    min-height: 50px;
    background: #4F5467;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9;
}

nav {
    background-color: #4F5467;
}

.card-container {
  margin-top: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid row p-0 m-0">
            <div class="col-2 bg-black sidebar">
              hello
            </div>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-dark inline">
                    <ul class="d-flex navbar-custom navbar-nav mr-auto d-inline">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inicio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Perfil</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Publicar</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Cerrar Sesión</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            <div class="col-10 p-0 m-0 body">
                
                <div class="col-md-10 offset-1 card-container">
                    <div class="card mt-3 border-0 rounded-0">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                        <p class="card-text">
                          Some quick example text to build on the card title
                          and make up the bulk of the card's content.
                        </p>
                        <a href="#!" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                        <a href="#!" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card mt-3 border-0 rounded-0">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                        <p class="card-text">
                          Some quick example text to build on the card title
                          and make up the bulk of the card's content.
                        </p>
                        <a href="#!" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                        <a href="#!" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card mt-3 border-0 rounded-0">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                        <p class="card-text">
                          Some quick example text to build on the card title
                          and make up the bulk of the card's content.
                        </p>
                        <a href="#!" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                        <a href="#!" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card mt-3 border-0 rounded-0">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                        <p class="card-text">
                          Some quick example text to build on the card title
                          and make up the bulk of the card's content.
                        </p>
                        <a href="#!" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                        <a href="#!" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card mt-3 border-0 rounded-0">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                        <p class="card-text">
                          Some quick example text to build on the card title
                          and make up the bulk of the card's content.
                        </p>
                        <a href="#!" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                        <a href="#!" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card mt-3 border-0 rounded-0">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                        <p class="card-text">
                          Some quick example text to build on the card title
                          and make up the bulk of the card's content.
                        </p>
                        <a href="#!" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                        <a href="#!" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Yes it is. You said you were trying to mimic that website's layout. I'm afraid css is pretty standard across websites. If that isn't what you wanted, what do you want?

Comment: I'm doing it with bootstrap, and I want the fixed navbar to stay and put the menu to the right according to my code, but it breaks when I put the position: fixed to the navbar

Comment: Updated. Let me know if there's anything else.

Answer (score 0):

use [sticky position](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/) with `top:0` and `z-index:99` for the nav bar :

```
.navbar{
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

here's a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/takius/de70temq/2/

or if you want `position: fixed`, you'll need to set a `margin-top` for the div right after it :

```
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 100%;
}

<div class="col-md-10 offset-1" style="margin-top:70px;">
```

here's a fiddle for that : https://jsfiddle.net/takius/de70temq/3/